# Delete multi table without join

Tags: sql, join, hsqldb, sql-delete

I have two tables T1 and T2. C1 is the primary key of T1, C2 is a foreign key of T2 that references the column C1 of T1. I want to delete the rows of T2 that verify a particular condition. A simple DELETE can be used :

```
DELETE FROM T2 WHERE <condition>;
```

But, I also want to delete the rows of T1 that are related to the rows deleted by the previous statement. For example, if the row R2 (of T2) has been deleted by the previous statement, I also want to delete the row R1 (of T1) with a primary key referenced by R2.
I know that there is a possibility to use DELETE statements with JOIN, but I use an HSQLDB in-memory database that doesn't support this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you use ON DELETE CASCADE, then you can always perform the delete this way:

```
DELETE FROM T1 WHERE T1.C1 IN (SELECT T2.C2 FROM T2 WHERE <condition>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the situation should have been the other way round, on delete of a row from T1, all rows from T2 with the foreign reference should have been deleted : `ON DELETE CASCADE` (Set this on foreign relation)

For deleting from more than one table,
This should work ([MySQL Delete Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)):
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]

Comment: Like you said the situation should have been inverse, and I use ON DELETE CASCADE. When the instance of T1 will be deleted, all the rows (of other tables) I want to delete will be deleted. The problem is I'm using HSQLDB and I don't know if multi table DELETE are supported.